# Uibutton does not recognize taps when moved to navbar region

Tags: ios, uibutton, uinavigationbar

In my app the user can move the navigation bar and find a uibutton underneath. The button fails to register taps when located underneath where the navigation bar would be. The button works fine when placed away from the navigation bar. How can I make sure the button recognizes taps when visible?

Comment: Are you sure its linked correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is linked correctly because it works if I move the position outside of the navigationbar. All code is to simply move the button into the navbar region when the navbar disappears

Answer (score 0):

Uinavigationbar will not recognize touches in navigation region if navigation bar is set to opaque. I solved by temporarily setting bar to translucent while hidden